# Date pipe bug angular 4.4

Tags: javascript, angular

I am running into the following problem when using the angular date pipe. If I modify a date at all, then the pipe doesn't work. If I use `new Date()` it works fine. Why is this?

```
getDate(){
    const currentDate = new Date();
    currentDate.setMonth(currentDate.getMonth() + 1);
    return currentDate;
}
```

---

```
<p>{{ getDate() | date}}</p>
```

---

```
ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Invalid Date' for pipe 'DatePipe'
at invalidPipeArgumentError (common.es5.js:2610)
```

Comment: can you console log it for me before the return?

Comment: It works for me in a plunker... try here https://embed.plnkr.co/w2FVfKlWP72pzXIsfsCU/

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/wQCrKaQxjpsrUzAYQmkR?p=preview <-- working example using the latest angular release

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention I am using angular-cli, maybe that is the cause? Log of the old date and new date are exactly the same + 1 month